# Angular 2+ confirmation page after HTTP POST to Web API

Tags: javascript, angular

First question here... I am tasked with enhancing an Angular application and I have started with NO angular experience.  I do have javascript experience, but  usually stick with Java (JSP's, and yes, javascript).  I think I've done reasonably well, considering, but I've run into this issue:

When submitting to the Web API, everything works!  But now comes the enhancement, add a page that has a large amount of text and info on it that is static, except for one or two items, including a confirmation number (the important part).  This page must replace the template/page that data was submitted from as it is the last thing the user should see.

I can return the confirmation number and display it on the page that does the submission, but that's not the mission.  I need to replace that page with a new one.

Because of the previous architecture of the application, we aren't using routing, but are using "steps" ... using the mdl-stepper libraries.

I have thought of simply making it another step in the process, but don't want to go to a "Success" page/display when the posting may have failed.

Simply typing this out has given me a few additional ideas, but if anyone has a truly simple way of doing this, I would appreciate any input.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the call to the method that actually makes the post:

```
  this.http.postQuestionnaireForm(this.customerIntake)
  .subscribe(
    data => this.response = JSON.stringify(data),
    error => alert(error),
    () => console.log("Finished")
  );
```

And here is the method that the above method calls:

```
  postQuestionnaireForm(customerIntake: String) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(customerIntake);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: "post" });

    return this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, body, options)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Again, my thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*The truth is that the question is superfluous, the reason you could not solve it is because you do not know the language, but I will answer it anyway because it can help more people to understand the two approaches that I will explain.*

As I understand you want to be on one page and change just the view in the following case:

1. You send HTTP Request and receive data from Web API endpoint.
2. You want to change the current view of the page to some new text and inject the data from Web API to specific field in the view.

---

From my experience with Angular, I will suggest two ways to get the job done. The first way will be a bit ugly but the second way will be more elegant but it will require more work to do. (and some advanced Angular tools)

## First approach

This approach it pretty simple (but not so elegant), you put all your code inside your HTML and TS file. we will use *ngIf to switch the view.
I will try to write my code as closely as possible to your code.
I will create variable called 'response' and it will be null, once we receive the data from Web API, we will assign the data to our variable 'response', let's look at some example.

TypeScript:

```
export class AppComponent {
  //#region Members
  public response: any;
  //#endregion

  //#region Constructor
  public constructor() {
    this.response = null;
  }
  //#endregion

  //#region Public Methods
  public postQuestionnaireForm(customerIntake) {
    console.log('postQuestionnaireForm(customerIntake)', customerIntake);

    this.http.postQuestionnaireForm(customerIntake)
      .subscribe(
        data => this.response = JSON.stringify(data),
        error => alert(error),
        () => console.log('Finished')
      );
  }
  //#endregion
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="response === null">
  <!-- This section will contain the required fields for HTTP Call. -->
  <form>
    <!-- More inputs here -->
  </form>
</div>

<div *ngIf="response !== null">
  <!-- This section contains the static data -->
  Some data, static data
  Some data, static data
  Some data, static data
  Some data, static data
  {{ data }}
  Some data, static data
  Some data, static data
</div>
```

And by using your function 'postQuestionnaireForm()', when the data will come back from Web API, response variable will be changed and the DOM will respond accordingly.

---

## Second approach

In this approach we will create 3 components.

1. Father component, name: AppComponent.
2. Child1 component, name: FormComponent.
3. Child2 component, name: DataComponent.

#### AppComponent

TypeScript:

```
export class AppComponent {
  //#region Members
  public state: number;
  @ViewChild(DataComponent) dataComponent: DataComponent;
  //#endregion

  //#region Constructor
  public constructor() {
    this.state = 1;
  }
  //#endregion

  //#region Public Methods
  public emitterFunction(data) {
    this.state = 2;
    this.dataComponent.setData(data);
  }
  //#endregion
}
```

HTML:

```
<div [hidden]="state !== 1">
  <app-form (emitte)="emitterFunction($event)"></app-form>
</div>

<div [hidden]="state !== 2">
  <app-data></app-data>
</div>
```

#### FormComponent

TypeScript:

```
export class FormComponent {
  //#region Members
  @Output() emitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  //#endregion

  //#region Constructor
  constructor() { }
  //#endregion

  //#region Public Methods
  public postQuestionnaireForm(customerIntake) {
    console.log('postQuestionnaireForm(customerIntake)', customerIntake);

    this.http.postQuestionnaireForm(customerIntake)
      .subscribe(
        data => this.emitter.emit(JSON.stringify(data))
        error => alert(error),
        () => console.log('Finished')
      );
  }
  //#endregion
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  <!-- More inputs here -->
  inputs
</form>
```

#### DataComponent

TypeScript:

```
export class DataComponent {
  //#region Members
  public data: any;
  //#endregion

  //#region Constructor
  constructor() {
    this.data = null;
  }
  //#endregion

  //#region Public Methods
  public setData(data: any): void {
    this.data = data;
  }
  //#endregion
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
Some data, static data
Some data, static data
Some data, static data
Some data, static data
{{ data }}
Some data, static data
Some data, static data
</div>
```

---

It's important to mention that we divided the view to 2 separate components which can act independently.
With this separation it's easier to maintain, easier to understand, but it's more complicated for beginners in Angular framework.

Some things to explain:

- @ViewChild - With this we get reference to our child component, we use it to get reference to DataComponent, so we can pass the data from FormComponent.
- EventEmitter - It's class that throws data to parent component, as you can see we added this in FormComponent and we called it when HTTP Request finished.
  At AppComponent HTML, we added reference to function when the emitter is being activated, it will pass the data from child component to father component in this specific function, and then we take the data and pass it to DataComponent.
- [hidden] - I used this because of important reason, I wanted to use *ngIf, but there is a problem, with *ngIf the HTML doesn't even exist, therefore at the beginning the HTML " " doesn't even exist.
  when we use [hidden] the HTML exist but it's hidden, so we have reference to DataComponent and we can use "setData(data)" function.